# Template tags not rendering in HTML

Tags: django, django-templates

I am building a skeleton django website, but can't manage to get the template tags to render for what I thought would be a simple test. Currently, the template tags just appear as text (i.e. it just says '{{ test }} and end' when I look at the website.

I am sure the problem is obvious, but I am not very experienced with django. I am not running into any errors though, so if there is any debugging advice that would be helpful.

Please let me know if I have missed any key information.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Forms

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'kb/home.html', {'test': 'begining'})
```

**home.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kinbank</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi there!</p>
        <p>{{ test }} and end </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register your app in the `settings.py` file in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section?  I copy/pasted your code and it works for me provided you registered your app.

You also need to make sure you have your templates in your `app/templates` folder.

Lastly, make sure in your `settings.py` file you have `APP_DIRS = True`. That way Django will traverse your app looking for the templates folder and find your html file.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```